# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 bug?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction

I have a code snippet as follows:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
......................
...................
size_t MyCalass::MyFunction() const
{
   using boost::lambda::_1;
   using boost::lambda::_2;
   using boost::lambda::bind;

   return std::accumulate(m_memberObj.begin(), m_memberObj.end(),
      size(), (_1 += bind(&MyCalass::GetLength, _2)));
}
```

Here, definitely, the boost::lambda::bind call is written in the last line of the function. But I get compile errors. It looks like this:

```
Error   70  error C2784: 'const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::lambda_functor_base<boost::lambda::arithmetic_assignment_action<Action>,boost::tuples::tuple<boost::lambda::lambda_functor<T>,boost::lambda::lambda_functor<Arg>>>> boost::lambda::operator +=(const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<T> &,const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<Arg> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<T> &' from 'stlp_std::basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Alloc>::size_type'   z:\3rdParty\boost_1_41_0_patched\boost\lambda\detail\operator_lambda_func_base.hpp  225
```

When I change my code like this:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
......................
...................
size_t MyCalass::MyFunction() const
{
   using boost::lambda::_1;
   using boost::lambda::_2;
   using boost::lambda::bind;

   return std::accumulate(m_memberObj.begin(), m_memberObj.end(),
      size(), (_1 += boost::lambda::bind(&MyCalass::GetLength, _2)));
}
```

it compiles correctly.

Is this a compiler bug? Is there a patch for this??

Comment: Is using namespace boost in code?

Comment: May be, but does it matter if in the function it is explicitly written **using boost::lambda::bind;**?